# Having trouble sending data from html to python using flask

Tags: python, html

I have an HTML index page that sends input data to a python script which processes the data and outputs it in a 2nd HTML page. On a local host, the process works fine and the data is displayed as desired. But when I try to host the process online, I get an error saying the URL cannot be found. If it helps, I'm using Heroku.

Apologies in advance for any poor lingo. I only just started learning how to code recently.

1st HTML

```
<form action = "https://webaddress/result" method = "POST">
    <h1> Enter info: </h1>
    <input type="text" name="info">

    <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

Python:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
from bs4   import BeautifulSoup
import requests

# https://doi.org/10.2118/21513-MS
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def student():
    return render_template('Trial.html')

@app.route('/result.html',methods = ['POST', 'GET'])
def result():
    return render_template("result.html",result = output)

if __name__ == '__main__':
   app.run(debug = True)
```

The input in the 1st HTML would be sent to the python section to be broken down and rearranged (left out that part so the python code wouldn't be too long) before being output into result.html. This worked on a local host using http://localhost:5000/ and http://localhost:5000/result.

When I run it on Heroku, I get the error message:

Not Found

The requested URL /result was not found on this server.

Update: Problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

Having some issues understanding your results() function. `output` isn't defined anywhere and `type` isn't used at all.

I believe your `action` parameter is incorrect.

Try:`<form action="/result" method = "POST">`

Here is a working version of what I hacked together for you:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/', methods=['GET'])
def home():
    return '''
    <form action="/result" method = "POST">
    <h1> Enter info: </h1>
    <input type="text" name="info">

    <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>

    </form>
    '''

@app.route('/result',methods = ['POST', 'GET'])
def result():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        type = ''
        if 'info' in request.form:
            result = request.form['info']

    return result


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True, port=8888, host='0.0.0.0')
```

Comment: Sorry, neither of the codes were copied in their entirety because I thought they'd be too long. The output and type are used in the parts that I left out. I'll give it a shot and post back. Thank you!

Comment: So I tried changing the action parameter but I still get the same error message

Comment: Can you paste the full error message?

EDIT: I realize the error is above, but is that the full text of the error?

Comment: That is it exactly.

Comment: Would you mind posting the full python file?

Also, a rough structure of your `templates` and `static` directories?

Since it works locally, there is something up with how Heroku is interpreting your request.

I'd like to try hosting my own to see if I can get it working :)

Comment: I don't mind but the python file is a few hundred lines and I'm not sure if there is a hard post limit? Also, the last line of my python file:

    return render_template("result.html",result = output)

Since Heroku doesn't allow static pages, could calling an html page to display the results be the problem?

Comment: I have posted the full python file.

Answer (score 0):

Your form refers to `/result` (no `.html` extension), but your route is for `/result.html` (*with* the extension). Try removing the `.html` from your route:

```
@app.route('/result', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def result():
    return render_template("result.html", result=output)
```